# C# Winforms DataGridView Cell Formatting Abnormal Behaviour

Tags: c#, datagridview

_I have a conditional row formatting setup for my `DataGridview`however whenever data is binded to it on first load, conditional formatting has no effect and infact formatting is applied to all the rows. But if the data inside the datagridview is reloaded cell formatting is fine. I can't understand when a condition is put in place it ignores it and applies the formatting to all the cells.

Here is my code

```
private void SetupData()
{
    dgview.DataSource = Data;
}

private void dgview_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Status")
    {                
        if (e.Value != null && (string)e.Value != "OK")
        {                    
           dgview.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
           dgview.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;                    
        }
    }            
}
```

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs event. Does it enter there on the 1st load?

Comment: @mjwills sorry was a typo there. I have fixed it now

Comment: @TaW the answer to your question is it does. Which is what am not able to understand :(

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem from the posted code.